# iPhone 6 discharging instead of charging

Tags: iphone, battery, charging

I have an iPhone 6. It's (unfortunately but unavoidably) had repairs at a third-party repair shop for a new battery, and later a new USB connector - I think the contacts finally wore out, I use it a lot.

Now, suddenly, my phone is complaining about my cable, which I'm fairly sure is an authentic Apple cable, and failing to charge my phone. I can still transfer photos and use the hotspot, but even though the "lightning bolt" appears next to the battery icon, the % charge value is going down, rather than up, and rather fast!

Before resorting to another trip to the third-party repair place, is there anything I can try, or check, to see if I can get it to start charging again?

Yesterday:

[image]

Today:

[image]

Today (five minutes after the 53% screenshot!)

[image]

Comment: (1) if it has programs running - expecially graphic and network intensive ones - it may be using more power than what is getting by the cable (2) if you're not using the original charger, verify it's powerful (number of Watts) enough, expecially if you're charging more things together (3) verify the contacts are clean (no lint)

Comment: @GioValerio thanks! See [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313506/iphone-6-discharging-instead-of-charging?noredirect=1#comment397827_313509). OK I'll check the contacts, and for lint. I'd never thought of that, but it's a good idea!

Comment: It's possible that the battery is degrading fast and not able to hold charge.

Comment: @GioValerio see my other [comment](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313506/iphone-6-discharging-instead-of-charging#comment398270_313509). It seems to have resolved itself. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Mac compter you can use you can connect iphone to the comuter and use [coconut battery](https://www.coconut-flavour.com/coconutbattery/). This Mac app will give you information about your battery. Best to have your phone fully charged if you can do that. It will work though without that constraint. I used it and it showed me that even though phone was fully charged it only had about 50% charge stored. My battery was dying.

Based on your graphics though it appears your cable or charger is not adequate for your phone. I'd check the battery first. If battery is ok, you might try a different cable and see how that works.

Comment: Thanks I only use the USB charger that came with my phone, or my MacBook Air to charge, never anything else. I've tried both with identical results. OK I'll look into the app for my laptop, but the battery is only a month or two old. Also, there are no apps running on my phone (that I'm aware of!). Besides Safari, I don't really use apps. The cable is about 6 months old and has been working fine. I'll see if I can locate another cable though, thanks!

Comment: Oh, the battery is 5 months old, time flies! https://security.stackexchange.com/a/167812/115702

Comment: should still be good though.

Comment: Unless they slipped me a "fourth-party battery". Being a foreigner here, anything is possible.

Comment: true but hope not.

Comment: After several more iterations, jigglings, un-pluggings and re-pluggings, the problem has disappeared and not returned. I'm going to blame it on some mystery contaminant on one of the plugs terminals, (e.g. lint as [suggested](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/313506/iphone-6-discharging-instead-of-charging#comment397826_313506)) or maybe the cable is starting to fail. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I would try an iPad charger capable of 2.1 amps 5V, knowing this is not usually advisable, attaining a full charge might overcome the apparent drain you're experiencing and correct the fault. Be sure to monitor its temperature as it will heat up and charge quickly.

Comment: well... let me know how it goes then! I'll stick to standard issue.

Comment: Well, why would you ask me to "let you know how it goes then!"? As my batteries always charge up dependably. just li with the charger you declare faithful to, uhoh. Good luck!

Comment: Since I don't have any apps running or videos playing, the current used by the phone should be minimal, and so my laptop's USB port or the iPhone's original charger should have plenty of current unless the phone or cable have a problem. Simply adding more current shouldn't help, and might even be dangerous if there is some unusual problem with the phone's battery or charging electronics. It's better to find the source of the trouble and fix it.